# ColdFusion 11 - consuming axis-1 web services

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We are moving from CF9 to CF11.  One thing that has changed is that CF11 now publishes and consumes axis-2 web services, while CF9 worked with axis-1 web services.

So, we have a bunch of axis-1 web services that we would rather not go back and re-factor. We have seen that there are settings you can add to code to specify the version, but would like to avoid that if possible. There is a setting in the CF11 administrator on the web services screen that is a toggle between axis-2 and axis-1 (with a default to axis-2).

What does that toggle do?

We were hoping that it could be used to set the server to publish and consume axis-1 web services by default, but a quick test of that theory did not seem to work.

Without re-factoring are there other options?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried that toggle? AFAIK it should do just what you need.

Comment: *a quick test of that theory did not seem to work* Are you testing with brand new web services, as opposed to existing services whose stubs may already be cached? *What does that toggle do?* http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/axis-2-and-axis-1-compatibility-issues

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.  Yes. Have tried the toggle. I'm testing with CF9 running on port 80 and the express version of 11 on port 8500, so I can try the same call on both.  I'm not sure how to clear the cache, so I stopped the express CF11 and restarted it, but has the same results.  The error message is "Cannot generate stub objects for web service invocation." In the details there is reference to org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.  Also tried adding this axis-1 web service via the CF11 Admin screen, but it does not accept it (toogle is on version 1).  I had read the blog post.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I follow that last part. Are you saying you *did* try it with a brand new web service? *RE: not sure how to clear the cache* See Milan's comments in the link above. In short, CF only generates the web service stubs once, when you first consume it. They remain "cached" until you delete/refresh the web service, which can be done programmatically or via the CF Admin. IIRC, you can also delete the stub .class files for the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can specify the axis version at multiple levels.**

See [Axis-2 and Axis-1 compatibility issues](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/axis-2-and-axis-1-compatibility-issues)

Basically besides at the server level you specified but it sounds like you want a more granular control.

**You can do this at the application level in the application.cfc:**

```
<cfset this.wssettings.version.consume = "2">
```

**Or even on a call by call basis such as this:**

```
ws = createObject("webservice"
                   , "http://localhost:8500/mycfc.cfc?wsdl"
                   , {wsversion="2"}
                 )
```

or this

```
<cfinvoke webservice = "http://localhost:8500/mycfc.cfc?wsdl" 
        method="echo" 
        wsversion="2" 
        returnVariable="foo" >
```

I'm not sure but you may have to use refreshWSDL to ensure that the proxy classes are regenerated for Axis-2 (*If so this would be a one time thing so you would do it like this when testing and then remove the refreshWSDL*)

```
<cfinvoke webservice = "http://localhost:8500/mycfc.cfc?wsdl" 
          method="echo" 
          wsversion="2" 
          returnVariable="foo" 
          refreshWSDL="yes">
```

Comment: Thanks. We had some code that may run on either 9 or 11, as our upgrade process was going to take a while.  I did a check on server version and added the wsversion="2" parameter if it was 11.  Also, good info about the refreshWSDL parameter.

Comment: Glad to help and of course thanks to Milan Chandna for posting the info